# imported glb file is hollow, how to fix?

Tags: modeling

im trying to import this glb file containing texture, model and animation.

when i import it into blender (latest), it has this weird hollowed out look. the face is not visible until you appear it from inside.

anyways, hope somebody can help me how to correct render.

here is the glb file https://filebin.net/hwkmdsfpvzlmg5r5/Teisel_Bonne__Cutscene_.glb?t=g2bmzav0

[image]

you can see the texture is turned inside out in particular the face is hollow and the face texture can only be visible when rotating the model.how do i fix this?

I played with the normals but it still missing bunch of faces. I used mesh ---> recalculate normals outside.

[image]

Comment: @Timaroberts thx I edited the question to include screenshot.

Comment: Try to recalculate the normals. Also there seems something wrong with your materials... try to remove one by one to figure out the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by normals?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is easily overlooked, and is found in your material settings.
You have [*backface culling*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#backface-culling) turned on, and not all faces are facing the same direction giving you the strange result you are seeing.

[image]

Turn off backface culling and this should fix the problem.

[image]